# Java - Digital signature using private key for sending data to an external web service

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, digital-signature

I need to connect to an external webservice from my Java application running on Tomcat 6. I have an SSL certificate for my domain purchased and installed on my server. Now I need to connect to an external service and use my certificate private key to digitally sign any data going to the service using SHA-256 hash and 128-bit salt length.  How can I use the private key to create this signature?  Can I pick any values for the salt?  Will they be able to decrypt it using my public key from the SSL certificate?

Can I use the [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) library for this? Any code or tutorials on the subject would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that signing and encrypting are not the same thing. If you sign with your private key, they'll be able to _verify_ the signature with your public key, but no encryption takes place (so there's no decryption).

Answer (score 0):

The JCA documentation provides an example for using `Signature` (under [Generating and Verifying a Signature Using Generated Keys](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#SigEx). You'd use `SHA256withRSA` instead of `SHA1withDSA`, as it's supported by the [SunRsaSignProvider](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunRsaSignProvider) (assuming it's an RSA key). You shouldn't need BouncyCastle for this.

If you want to use BouncyCastle, you'd need to do something along these lines (I've haven't tried this particular code):

```
AsymmetricKeyParameter keyParam = PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(...);
// You might need to cast to private key to RSAPrivateKey 
// and get its attributes manually here.

SHA256Digest digest = new SHA256Digest();
RSADigestSigner signer = new RSADigestSigner(digest);
signer.init(true, keyParam);
signer.update(... data to sign, start, length, ...);
byte[] signature = signer.generatedSignature();
```

(If you're doing this from within a webapp, you'd also need the webapp to be able to gain access to this private key, which may be a security risk should the webapp be compromised. It might be worth considering using a different key/certificate, even self-signed, if the remote party is willing to accept it.)

Comment: The remote party has to accept my certificate? I'm trying to understand how to use the private key from my purchased SSL certificate to sign these messages I send but I don't know how to retrieve that in my application.

Comment: The remote party has be able to verify your signature against something: that will be the public key in the matching certificate, which also ties that key to your server's identity. It will need to get hold of that certificate or at least know somehow from which public key to verify the signature. (For example, with XML-DSig, the certificate can be bundled with the signed message.) It may then verify your certificate against a CA it trusts.

Comment: Getting the private key from the webapp is another problem. Usually, containers like Tomcat isolate their keystore (and their own configuration in general) from the webapps (usually the default security manager's policy, when enabled). This allows the webapps to be "sandboxed" so as not to be able to gain admin access on the container itself. You might be able to edit the security policy to allow the webapp to load the keystore, or make the keystore file readable from the webapp (you could even pass it via JNDI). Beware that a flaw in your webapp could compromise your private key.

Comment: It's not clear what kind of web service you want to talk to, but you might want to look at WS-Security, as @Biju Kunjummen suggested instead of doing the signature yourself. [Apache Rampart](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/) might also be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using a webservice stack for this:
For eg. an approach for WS-Security client using Apache CXF - http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html

One more good reference: http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/cxf_x509_profile